# What do empty braces mean in struct declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a cut-down definition of a `struct`, showing only the point at issue.

```
struct Entry {
    // bookkeeping record for managing solution search
    std::array<std::array<bool, DIM>, DIM> filled;   // which holes have been filled
    std::array<std::array<char, MAX>, MAX> cells;    // individual cell entries, 0=empty
    std::vector<Constraint> overlaps;
    std::vector<Hole*>::iterator candidates;
    Entry() = default;
};
```

This was actually a mistake.  I was thinking that the default constructor would zero-initialize the arrays, but it just fills them with random garbage.  I now know I need to write the default constructor, but I am confused by the behavior I ran across when testing.

This is a cut-down version of my test function:

```
void testEntry(void) {
    Entry e;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    e.cells[1][2] = 'a';
    e.filled[0][0] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++j)
            std::cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<e.cells[i][j]<<std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; ++j)
            std::cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<e.filled[i][j]<<std::endl;
}
```

When I ran this, the `filled` and `cells` arrays contained random garbage, and eventually I found my mistake.   While debugging, I changed the declaration `Entry e;` to `Entry e{};` and the modified code appears to work as I intended, but I don't understand why.

I'm not quite able to follow the documentation.  Under [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) it says that, "If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with a default constructor, value-initialization is performed."  This is pretty clear, but when I go to [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), I can't figure out which, if any, of the cases apply.
Is seems like this clause under [zero-intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) is being applied
"If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored," but I don't see how to get here.

More than anything, I'm wondering if this behavior is actually defined in the specs, or if it might be different with a different compiler.  (I'm using clang under Xcode 7.2.1).

Comment: " if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor; "

Comment: You tagged this question C++11, but are you *only* interested in C++11, or also in C++14? C++14 makes this aggregate initialisation, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `[...]` == brackets, `(...)` == parentheses, `{...}` == braces.  Your code has all three, and you mention 'brackets' only in the title - one has to work unnecessarily hard to figure out what the question is here.  The default constructor doesn't not fill arrays with "random junk" - it does exactly nothing - the random junk is just what ever happened to be in the memory used - and it is not necessarily random.

Comment: the compiler provided "default" constructor is really that. it does nothing with the member variables but leaves them with their default. and `bool` has no default value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What do empty brackets mean in struct declaration?

`T object {};` is syntax for [value initialization (4)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Without the curly brackets, the object would be [default initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

To be pedantic, this is not a "struct declaration". It is declaration of a variable.

> when I go to value initialization, I can't figure out which, if any, of the cases apply.

This one applies:

> 2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor; (since C++11)

And that is how we get to zero initialization. Your interpretation of the zero initialization rules is correct.

> I'm wondering if this behavior is actually defined in the specs

The rules in the linked pages are based on the standard, not on a specific implementation. The behaviour is defined.

Comment: Thanks.  the phrase "defaulted default constructor" is what I overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

The wording in the Standard changed between C++11 and C++14, and the end result is similar but not identical.

---

This code is *list-initialization* because a braced list (albeit empty) is the initializer. In C++11 the following quote from [dcl.init.list]/3 applies:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

However in C++14 the same section starts with a different bullet point:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed

In this case, `Entry` is an aggregate because it meets the conditions for one ([dcl.init.aggr]/1):

> An aggregate is an array or a class with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions

The term "user-provided" excludes a defaulted function.

The behaviour of aggregate initialization is covered in [dcl.init.aggr], which says that successive members of the list are taken as initializer for the members of the aggregate.  When there are fewer list members than aggregate members, then [dcl.init.aggr]/7 applies:

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if there is no *brace-or-equal-
>   initializer*, from an empty initializer list.

This is saying that, for example, `e.overlaps` is initialized in the same way as `std::vector<Constraint> overlaps{};` would be.

You may note that this is a recursive definition for aggregates. When we get to something that is not an aggregate (e.g. `std::vector`) , then the second bullet point in [dcl.init.list]/3 will apply, which is the first one from C++11: value-initialization.

---

Comparing the C++11 with the C++14, there is a small difference: in C++14 there is no step of *zero-initializing* the entire object before calling default constructors of members.  Instead, only the sub-objects without user-provided constructors will be zero-initialized.   In C++14, struct padding in `Entry` might not be initialized to zero bits. (There could be padding after the `std::array` members). Similarly, if the `std::vector`'s internals contain any members not initialized by its constructor; they would remain uninitialized, and not zero-initialized.